# How to go 1 level back for a directory path stored in a variable

Tags: go, path

I'm trying to go back 1 level back in a stored variable in Go Lang, how could I do this?

```
Origin:
"/root/path"

Expected:
"/root/"
```

There's a function that could do that automatically? or I have to do it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parent directory can always be referred to by `..`, so you can append that to your path.

For example:

```
p := "/root/path/"
p = filepath.Clean(filepath.Join(p, ".."))
fmt.Println(p)
// "/root"
```

If `path` is not a directory itself (or you are certain that it will not end in a path separator), then you can use the `Dir` function to get the containing directory. [Dir](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Dir) *returns all but the last element of path, typically the path's directory*:

```
p := "/root/path"
p = filepath.Dir(p)
fmt.Println(p)
// "/root"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def directory_back_levels(path='', steps=0):
    try:
        # check type
        if not isinstance(steps, int) or not isinstance(path, str):
            return ''
        # performance return path if steps 0
        if steps < 1:
            return path

        # loop towrads steps and use os.path.dirname to get the previous directory
        new_path = path
        for i in range(steps):
            new_path = os.path.dirname(new_path)
        
        return new_path
    except Exception as e:
        print("error in directory_back_levels")
        raise e

Expected = directory_back_levels(path="/root/path", steps=1)
print(Expected)

notExpected = directory_back_levels(path="/root/static/images/new/image.png", steps=4)
print(notExpected)
```

[image]